# Checking rows of 2d ArrayList for specific values

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am trying to scan every row of a 2d array (100x100 sizes) and make sure that every row (and later column) will have only 1 instance of every integer 1 through 100. In the following code I am trying to make sure every row only has one instance of every integer 1 through 100, but obviously the syntax does not work. Is there any method that could push this through or what am I missing?

Thanks for any assistance

```
for(int i = 0; i<100; i++) {

        for (int j=0; j<100 ; j++) {
            if(2dARR.get(i).get(j).contains(1) && 2dArr.get(i).get(j).contains(2)(.....)) {
                System.out.println("FK");
            }

        }

    }
```

Comment: The crucial information is how did you defined the 2dARR object.

Comment: it is defined as arraylist<arraylist<Integer>>()

Comment: if(!arr2d.get(i).contains(j)){ System.out.println("FK"); } Seems more like what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i<100; i++) {
  Set<Integer> numbersInRow = new HashSet<Integer>();  
  for (int j=0; j<100 ; j++) {
    int num = 2dARR.get(i).get(j);
    if (num < 1 || num > 100) {
       // out of bounds, handle error
    }
    else {
       numbersInRow.add(num);
    }
  }
  // At this point we have the set of numbers found in the row, all guaranteed to be >=1 and <= 100
  if (numbersInRow.size() != 100) {
     // at least one number appeared more than once
  }
}
```

Comment: You could do this with a boolean array of size 100 and fill in the entries as you find them and assert that the entry hasn't already been used if you're really memory constrained.  But I'd avoid such a premature optimization.

If you need to figure out which number is missing, a TreeSet<Integer> would be easier to visually inspect.

Comment: `2dArr` is invalid as a variable name!

Answer (score 0):

Dump it into a Set, check that the size of the Array and Set are Equal. If they aren't, there are duplicates. If you get past that test, run a loop through the array and check that all values are greater than 0 and less than 101 (1-100).